# Wordpress Session Expires if Anonymous

Tags: wordpress, session, anonymous

I'm experiencing a strange problem, I'm a noobie in wordpress but I can't find any solution for this: in the production server, if (and only if) I'm not logged (I'm anonymous), session expires as I change the page. On local "server" (xampp), the same wordpress works fine even in  anonymous...

Can anyone help me to understand what's happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It was a mixing of things: W3TC on cache deleting, and URLs settings on Wordpress settings. In fact, when the site URL doen't match with wordpress url, it could give cache problems... then the bug with woocommerce and cart on anonymous user was issued by those two things!

Answer (score 0):

Reading this, it seems to be a W3TC plugin issue:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3-and-woocommerce-shopping-carts

There are some solutions here, I've combined them taking the most valid for my tastes, but no way to figure it out. Neither deleting the plugin, even this option is useless!

Don't know if it's possible that the plugin has corrupted something... I hope that this answer will be useful at least for someone else!